# React - update use state from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to update this use state so that when a button in `<FirstPage />` component is clicked the state should be updated. 
 I'm kinda stuck what is the best way to achieve this?

```
const SignUp = () => {
    const [display, setDisplay] = useState(true);
    const onClick = () => {
        setDisplay(false);
    };

    return (
        <>
            { display? <FirstPage changeState={onClick}/> : <SecPage/> }    
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Does your current code not work?

Comment: What you've done is a correct way, one of many (dependently on the app implementation) ways to update parent of a component by passing a callback function that allows the child to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this would be to pass the setDisplay item to FirstPage and then set it in the FirstPage component.

as in

```
    return (
          <>
            { display? <FirstPage setDisplay={setDisplay}/> : <SecPage/> }    
          </>
     );
```

then you could change the display state in the FirstPage component using the onclick for it to call a function to setDisplay(false) something like below.  you would then call the function using onClick={buttonClicked()}

```
   const buttonClicked = () => {
        setDisplay(false);
   }
```